# Excel VBA convert everything to text

Tags: excel, vba, type-conversion

I have tried converting my data to text. But it's not really text? If that makes sense.

So, this is my code

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1"). CurrentRegion
rng.NumberFormat = "@"
```

This code will convert everything to "text" but when I select some numbers, it shows the sum at the bottom right, which text isn't supposed to do so.

2nd thing is, after I have convert it to "text", I realise I have to click on the cell, press enter, then it will really become text format...

Comment: Setting the number format doesn't convert data, it just defines how you want to display data.

Comment: Look into converting the data to the string data type in vba

Comment: @FunThomas, Do you have any idea, how I can really convert them all to text? My data consist of numbers and characters.

Comment: @Brett, alrite! Will try. Thanks!

Comment: @jayl As a friendly pro-tip, numbers that are text can be easily converted to numbers with the `text to columns` function by selecting the whole row,  pressing text to columns, and just pressing OK without entering any options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Convert Numbers to Text

- Note that the single quote in front of a number will be ignored. Get its length or concatenate to prove it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertToText()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'rng.NumberFormat = "@" ' with or without
    Dim cCell As Range
    For Each cCell In rng.Cells
        If IsNumeric(cCell.Value) Then
            cCell.Value = "'" & CStr(cCell.Value)
        End If
    Next cCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this code, doesnt format my date to text, any idea?

Comment: Try just `cCell.Value = "'" & cCell.Text` in the loop (no `If`s).

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, thanks!! it works now! But I still have one issue- numbers that are very big (for eg, 90100100072625) <- the value will be converted to 9.01001E+14 <- and when I expend out, it just gives me the 0s i.e. 90100100000

Comment: Up to 15 digits, `cCell.Value` will show the 'full' number, but `cCell.Text` won't. Either implement an If statement to cover this, or format the cells containing these numbers as a number with 0 decimals to avoid scientific notation. As a 3rd option, even if there are more than 15 digits, you can always use the single quote (`'`) in front of the digits when entering these numbers.

Comment: Does not look correct with error values (#N/A! etc. will display as Error 20xx). Also will display the logical values always as TRUE and FALSE, which may not be what non-English people expect. `cCell.Text` would deal with those two cases, though.